# Setting Active Menu Item with CSS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div menu on a webpage that looks great, but I want to indicate the active page by changing the coloring on an element.

What I have tried does not work.

Fiddle me this, Batman: http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/rj39rup6/

This is the part of the CSS that works great, because I copied it from a website:

```
nav {
  background-color: #999999; /* silver */
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display:block;
  font-family: Stencil, sans-serif, monospace;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > a > .caret {
  border-top: 4px solid #CC0000; /* Red */
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  transition: color 0.1s linear; 
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #CC0000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 ); /* blue shark */
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); /* white */
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
  border-top-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); /* white */
}
nav > ul > li > div {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 ); /* blue shark */
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

The html is:

```
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="miHome"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
      <li id="miAbout"><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
      <li id="miContact"><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var d = document.getElementById("miHome");
  d.className = 'selected';
});
```

The CSS I added (that is probably done incorrectly), is:

```
.selected nav > ul > li > div {
  background-color: rgb( 189, 189, 189 ); /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected nav > ul > li > a {
  background-color: rgb( 189, 189, 189 ); /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 ); /* blue shark */
}
.selected nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgb( 189, 189, 189 ); /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
```

### Did I write my CSS wrong or use jQuery incorrectly? Could someone help me get this working?

Also, can someone that is better with web design suggest a better color selection for the active menu item? The website colors are Blue, Red, Gold and Silver (USMC Dress Blues).

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/rj39rup6/3/?

Comment: ``d.className = 'selected'`` isn't wrong but it is pure javascript and not jQuery.  Try instead ``$('#miHome').addClass('selected');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong chain after your target, `.selected`. Remove the  `nav > ul > li >` chain to access the elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("miHome");
  d.className = 'selected';
});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #999999;
  /* silver */
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: block;
  font-family: Stencil, sans-serif, monospace;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > a > .caret {
  border-top: 4px solid #CC0000;
  /* Red */
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #CC0000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  /* blue shark */
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* white */
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* white */
}
nav > ul > li > div {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  /* blue shark */
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.selected > div {
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected > a {
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected:hover {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  /* blue shark */
}
.selected:hover > a {
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="miHome"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="miAbout"><a href="About.aspx">About</a>
      </li>
      <li id="miContact"><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice Ammar. I love how that built in stuff works, too. Other answers on here have said I should access my elements on here differently, too, yet your version works. Which is best?

Comment: this code doesn't scale to other pages, this code won't work on the about page or any page besides the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is wrong. The class .selected is located wrong.

```
.selected > div {
  background-color: rgb( 189, 189, 189 ); /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected  > a {
  background-color: rgb( 189, 189, 189 ); /* lighter silver */
  color: black;
}
.selected:hover {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 ); /* blue shark */
}
.selected:hover > a {
  background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 ); /* blue shark */
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you aren't using jQuery properly.

```
var d = document.getElementById("miHome");
d.className = 'selected';
```

can be simplified to

```
$('#miHome').addClass('selected');
```

Also, your CSS isn't targeting the right elements. You are adding the selected class to the `li` element, not the parent of the `nav` element. So your CSS rules need to be adjusted.

Please see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e2a30ynb/2/
(I also removed some unused CSS declarations)

Comment: I like that shorter script. So, was I using Javascript and your version is jQuery? I am not good at either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change a color for li when his page href is load .. If this what you need you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // get path
  var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
   // get file name
  var filename = pathname[pathname.length-1];
  $('a[href="'+filename+'"]').closest('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

let me explain that a little bit .. say your `url = 'http://www.website.com/Default.aspx';`  we split that url to an array .. and get the file name for example(`Default.aspx`)  so we find the anchor which has `href="Default.aspx"` and use closest to get parent li for this anchor and addClass to it .. this code will make the same things with another anchors .. but be sure that your file name is a last variable in url array `/Default.aspx`   not `/Default.aspx?something=hhh`   hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

This code will add the class to the correct nav item on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  id = (function() {
    f = window.location.href.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    return "mi"+f.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + f.substr(1)
  })
  $("#"+id()).addClass("selected")
});
```